# Cloud Armor targets for policy disappears

Tags: target, policy, google-cloud-armor

We're experiencing a strange behaviour since about 10 days ...
I had some targets for my Cloud Armor policy correctly working since 2 years.
Last week I saw that my backends are worldwide available... and when I checked, my target list was empty.
I did the work again ... everything seemed to be ok .. and the day after .. same thing, empty list.
Today again ... after about 2 hours, my targets are somewhat automatically removed, without any trace or notification.
Is anybody experiencing a similar problem ?
Thanks in advance

Cloud Armor configuration

- select my policy
- add policy to new target
- select a loadbalancer backend
- click Add
  --> selected targets are listed --> OK I see my list with grren checks

Come back to Cloud Armor config sometime later --> target list is empty --> I expect the list to be the same I left

Comment: Check audit logging. Changes to a resource's metadata are logged including the principal that made the change.

Comment: Hi, I tried to have a look to audit logging. When I add the rule, I can see 2 lines with me as principal, one with a "response" field saying "operation type" compute.backendServices.setSecurityPolicy, "Progress 0" status RUNNING and the other just a request with @type: "type.googleapis.com/compute.backendServices.setSecurityPolicy"

Comment: 5 minutes later, same 2 lines buth with a service account as principal and with same payload, requests and responses ... no errors, no warnings, no other opertions audited .... and my target disappeared ...

Comment: I can see some errors related to fluentbit parsing issues and we had an anormal logging activity on mid may --> maybe an update to kubernetes gke versions / images  that leads to some bugs, incoherences ?

Comment: Look up the service account to see which IAM roles are attached. I am guessing your project is part of an organization and a service is deleting your Cloud Armor rules. The logs are telling who, now you have to find out more.

Comment: I looked at IAM, service account is xxx@container-engine-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com.

Comment: I looked back in logging and I found some calls from the same account to a strange API and after that, my targets seems to be removed. The API is v1.compute.networkEndpointGroups.detachNetworkEndpoints. Some time later, another call to v1.compute.networkEndpointGroups.attachNetworkEndpoints

Comment: [Details](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/service-accounts#gke-service-agents) for that service account.

Comment: ok .. but why this kind of service account removes my rules .... ?

Comment: The service account does not remove your rules. A process or person is using that service account's identity to remove your rules.

Comment: Yes, I see, but I can't find what or who is using it ... there are logs anywhere in GCP :-D

Comment: Hi, problem solved (thanks to GCP support). If you want to include a Backend service LB as a target ... you have to specify this in the corresponding BackendConfig objet yml. If you use the Cloud Armor console, the corresponding deploiment modification is temporary ... and overxritten at next automatic synch. I asked why you can use console to add a target .. if this modification is known as not permanent ... Thank you all for yours answers also :-)

Comment: Can you provide more details? I want to reproduce this issue if possible.

Comment: I had a yml for my backend service similar to this:apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: backendconfig-xxx-backend
  namespace: integration
spec:
  timeoutSec: 600
  connectionDraining:
    drainingTimeoutSec: 600
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: xxx-service-backend<br/> namespace: integration
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"80":"backendconfig-xxx-backend"}}'

Comment: And when I added my Backend to Cloud Armor choising it from the proposed list, I was added .. but removed after 5 minutes. I had to add the line   securityPolicy:
    name: "allow-elazur" in the spec part of BackendConfig object and my backend is now automaticcaly recognized as a target for Cloud Armor

Comment: I understand from support comment that adding a target via the console modifies yml ... only temporarely.

Comment: Support said "Please note that you should avoid changing the load balancer's configuration using methods outside of GKE. Your customizations to settings for the load balancer's objects – forwarding rules, target proxies, URL maps, backend services, and health checks – are overwritten when new resource changes are applied, during periodic syncs, or during cluster upgrades[7].

Comment: and ... So to associate cloud armor security policy with the GKE https load balancer correctly, you should create a “BackendConfig” Object and associate the BackendConfig object with the ingress. I would recommend you read the public documentation to know more details[8]."

Comment: Since your comments are long and have links, which are missing as comments, can you put everything in the question, please? In your last comment, you mention GKE. Is your backend a cluster? That detail should have been in your original post.